# what is the right way to initializa a database with flask_pymongo?

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, pymongo

I am trying to write a silly app so I can practice docker (I am try to learn Docker). So I have written a simple flask app using Mongo, but when I try to start i up I get an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anton\Desktop\cars\app.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.config["MONGO_URI"] = 'mongodb://' + os.environ['MONGODB_USERNAME'] + ':' + os.environ['MONGODB_PASSWORD'] + '@' + os.environ['MONGODB_HOSTNAME'] + ':27017/' + os.environ['MONGODB_DATABASE']
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'MONGODB_USERNAME'
```

I have been searching through the documentation and through several different threads in here and tried to use some other ways to define the app.config which works, but I would need it to be this way so I can add it in the `env` field in my docker-compose. This is the app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
import os
import json_logging, logging, sys

app = Flask(__name__)

json_logging.init_flask(enable_json=True)
json_logging.init_request_instrument(app)
logger = logging.getLogger("mongodb-service")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))

app.config["MONGO_URI"] = 'mongodb://' + os.environ['MONGODB_USERNAME'] + ':' + os.environ['MONGODB_PASSWORD'] + '@' + os.environ['MONGODB_HOSTNAME'] + ':27017/' + os.environ['MONGODB_DATABASE']
mongo = PyMongo(app)
db = mongo.db

@app.route('/')
def ping_server():
    return "Welcome to best website ever"

@app.route('/cars')
def get_stored_cars():
    # db = get_db()
    _cars = db.car_tb.find()
    cars = [{"brand": car["brand"], "model": car["model"]} for car in _cars]
    return jsonify({"cars": cars})
```

and I would like to pass it to my docker.compose.yml like this:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    container_name: cars_app
    image: latalavera/flask-app:1.4
    build: .
    environment:
      APP_ENV: "dev"
      APP_DEBUG: "False"
      MONGODB_DATABASE: cars_db
      MONGODB_USERNAME: root
      MONGODB_PASSWORD: pass
      MONGODB_HOSTNAME: mongodb-flask
    ports:
      - ${APP_PORT}:${APP_PORT}
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    networks:
      - app_network
```

Comment: Os.environ returns the environment variable  - in Windows initialised with the set command. It seems that your variables are not set - or did you do this elsewhere?

Comment: I am probably confused as I am learning Docker, but I thought the environment filed in the docker compose will create thoses environment variable for the container. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `build` and an `image` line in your docker compose. You likely want one or the other; you're either building from a dockerfile or using an image already built.

Comment: Setting both is meaningful; it gives a specific name to the built image.  (It's a potential problem if the Compose `image:` is the same as the Dockerfile `FROM` line.)

Comment: @Belly Buster I do not get what you mean I use the image field to provide a name to the image I build from the dockerfile. I have followed the documentation. As far and as little as I know that is correct. My issue is not being able to pass the os.environ variables I need to setup my app to the container

Comment: Right ok but you didn't post your dockerfile so it was unclear.